# How can I alter my code to make my sprite, which rotates in a circular orbit, jump up then back down when a user taps the screen?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, rotation

I'm trying to make my orange circle sprite, which orbits in a circular motion, jump at ant point in its rotation and fall back down again when the user taps the screen but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

I've tried taking the advice to somewhat similar post o here but have had no luck.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
    var node2AngularDistance: CGFloat = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 94.0/255, green: 63.0/255, blue: 107.0/255, alpha: 1)

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        sprite.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
        player.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 0+50, y: 0)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
        self.addChild(sprite)
        self.addChild(player)
    }

    //dont touch blue lines that discard code and don't allow you to undo

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let dt: CGFloat = 1.0/60.0 //Delta Time
        let period: CGFloat = 3 //Number of seconds it takes to complete 1 orbit.
        let orbitPosition = sprite.position //Point to orbit.
        let orbitRadius = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150) //Radius of orbit.

        let normal = CGVector(dx:orbitPosition.x + CGFloat(cos(self.node2AngularDistance))*orbitRadius.x ,dy:orbitPosition.y + CGFloat(sin(self.node2AngularDistance))*orbitRadius.y);
        self.node2AngularDistance += (CGFloat(Double.pi)*2.0)/period*dt;
        if (abs(self.node2AngularDistance)>CGFloat(Double.pi)*2) {
            self.node2AngularDistance = 0
        }
        player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx:(normal.dx-player.position.x)/dt ,dy:(normal.dy-player.position.y)/dt);



        //func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        //sprite.position = (touches.first! as! UITouch).location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        jump()
    }

    func jump() {
        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500))
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    }
}
```

The expected results would be a small circle sprite called player that rotates in circular orbit around a larger circle called sprite and when the user taps the screen, the player(small circle) would jump up then back down at any point in its orbit.The actual results are the the circle rotates around the larger circle but does not jump up when I click on the screen in the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

A jumpping state needs to record as : isJumpping. If isJumpping, the update will not perform, if this is what you need.

The second issue is after touching up, the player falls back to the orbital. A simple math is given here as the player directly falling to the circle.

But if the situation is complicated, you may consider to use PhysicsField to simulate the situation.

This is running in a Xcode 10 and playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
import simd

class GameScene: SKScene {
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
var node2AngularDistance: CGFloat = 0

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    print(100)
  //  backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 94.0/255, green: 63.0/255, blue: 107.0/255, alpha: 1)
     backgroundColor = SKColor.black

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    sprite.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    player.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: 0+50, y: 0)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.addChild(sprite)
    self.addChild(player)
}

//dont touch blue lines that discard code and don't allow you to undo

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    guard  !isJumpping else {

        return
    }

    let dt: CGFloat = 1.0/60.0 //Delta Time
    let period: CGFloat = 3 //Number of seconds it takes to complete 1 orbit.
    let orbitPosition = sprite.position //Point to orbit.
    let orbitRadius = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150) //Radius of orbit.


   let currentDistance = distance(double2(x: Double(orbitPosition.x), y: Double(orbitPosition.y)), double2(x: Double(player.position.x), y: Double(player.position.y)))
    if (  currentDistance > 150){

        player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx:(orbitPosition.x - player.position.x) ,dy:(orbitPosition.y - player.position.y));

        let x = Double(player.position.x) - Double(orbitPosition.x)
        let y = Double(player.position.y) - Double(orbitPosition.y)
        self.node2AngularDistance = CGFloat(acos(x/currentDistance))

   if y < 0 {

    self.node2AngularDistance = 2 * CGFloat.pi -  self.node2AngularDistance }

        return;
    }



    let normal = CGVector(dx:orbitPosition.x + CGFloat(cos(self.node2AngularDistance))*orbitRadius.x ,dy:orbitPosition.y + CGFloat(sin(self.node2AngularDistance))*orbitRadius.y);


    self.node2AngularDistance += (CGFloat(Double.pi)*2.0)/period*dt;
    if (abs(self.node2AngularDistance)>CGFloat(Double.pi)*2) {
        self.node2AngularDistance = 0
    }

    player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx:(normal.dx-player.position.x)/dt ,dy:(normal.dy-player.position.y)/dt);



    //func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    //sprite.position = (touches.first! as! UITouch).location(in: self)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
    jump()
}
private var isJumpping : Bool = false
func jump() {
    isJumpping.toggle()
    player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: (self.player.position.x - self.sprite.position.x) / 100.0, dy: (self.player.position.y - self.sprite.position.y) / 100.0))
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
    isJumpping.toggle()
    player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
}
}




class GameViewCointroller: UIViewController{

    var skview: SKView!



  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    skview = SKView.init(frame: view.bounds)
    let scene = GameScene.init(size: view.frame.size)
    skview.presentScene(scene)
    view.addSubview(skview)
   }


}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = GameViewCointroller()
```